# Revise scientific paper using package changes

Tags: article, changes, trackchanges

I am writing a scientif paper (Patter recognition Letter template)  and for the revision, I am using the package changes. **In the below code, the list of changes are not generated:** I used texStudio and texShop.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{lipsum}% <- For dummy text
\definechangesauthor[name={R G}, color=red]{rg}
\setremarkmarkup{(#2)}


    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-3]

    I eat \added[id=rg,remark={we need a preposition an}]{an} apple
    I buy \deleted[id=rg,remark={don't use a with plural}]{a} books.
    I buy \replaced[id=rg, remark={be positive}]{nice}{bad} car.


    \listofchanges[style=<list|summary>]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This code, as is, does produce a list of changes for me. Did you compile twice?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer, I am using the pattern recognition letter template, so I don't know what is the problem? yes I compile twice and deleted the log and aux files but it does not work! I am using texStudio

Comment: @MichaelPalmer, the problem seems from the template

Comment: If you delete the auxiliary files it can't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I mean: I delete it and I recompile again!

Comment: Where can one find this template?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  https://www.elsevier.com/journals/pattern-recognition-letters/0167-8655/guide-for-authors#20000

Comment: Then try again without deleting anything. And try your example above and not something we don't know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A wild guess: are you using the `final` option?

```
\documentclass[
%   final,
]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={R G}, color=red]{rg}
\setremarkmarkup{(#2)}

\begin{document}

I eat \added[id=rg,remark={we need a preposition an}]{an} apple
I buy \deleted[id=rg,remark={don't use a with plural}]{a} books.
I buy \replaced[id=rg, remark={be positive}]{nice}{bad} car.

\listofchanges[style=<list|summary>]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  that's the problem.

Comment: @BetterEnglish I bet that with a MWE that shows your problem, you would have received an answer much faster.

Comment: @samcarter: There was a MWE but it looks as if the claim of the question that it shows the problem was a bland lie.

Comment: +1 for deep insight into what the OP *wanted* to express...

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Crystal balls can sometimes be very helpful -- Stackexchange should send one to every user!

Comment: Here is the link for more options: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.pdf

Comment: BTW: you should not use `\listofchanges[style=<list|summary>]` but `\listofchanges[style=list]` or `\listofchanges[style=summary]`